# With Circe Json why is implicit resolution slower at runtime

Tags: json, scala, circe

Why is Circe Json slower with implicit decoder lookup compared to saving the implicit decoder to a val.

I would expect these to be the same because implicit resolution is done at runtime.

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.jackson
import io.circe.syntax._

private val decoder = implicitly[Decoder[Data.Type]]
def decode(): Either[Error, Type] = {
  jackson.decode[Data.Type](Data.json)(decoder)
}

def decodeAuto(): Either[Error, Type] = {
  jackson.decode[Data.Type](Data.json)
}


[info] DecodeTest.circeJackson             thrpt  200   69157.472 ± 283.285  ops/s
[info] DecodeTest.circeJacksonAuto         thrpt  200   67946.734 ± 315.876  ops/s
```

The full repo can be found here.
https://github.com/stephennancekivell/some-jmh-json-benchmarks-circe-jackson

Comment: Scala never resolves implicit at runtime

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider this much simpler case that doesn't involve circe or generic derivation at all:

```
package demo

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class OrderingBench {
  val items: List[(Char, Int)] = List('z', 'y', 'x').zipWithIndex
  val tupleOrdering: Ordering[(Char, Int)] = implicitly

  @Benchmark
  def sortWithResolved(): List[(Char, Int)] = items.sorted

  @Benchmark
  def sortWithVal(): List[(Char, Int)] = items.sorted(tupleOrdering)    
}
```

On 2.11 on my desktop machine I get this:

```
Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt         Score        Error  Units
OrderingBench.sortWithResolved  thrpt   40  15940745.279 ± 102634.860  ps/s
OrderingBench.sortWithVal       thrpt   40  16420078.932 ± 102901.418  ops/s
```

And if you look at allocations the difference is a little bigger:

```
Benchmark                                            Mode  Cnt    Score   Error   Units
OrderingBench.sortWithResolved:gc.alloc.rate.norm  thrpt   20  176.000 ±  0.001    B/op
OrderingBench.sortWithVal:gc.alloc.rate.norm       thrpt   20  152.000 ±  0.001    B/op
```

You can tell what's going on by breaking out `reify`:

```
scala> val items: List[(Char, Int)] = List('z', 'y', 'x').zipWithIndex
items: List[(Char, Int)] = List((z,0), (y,1), (x,2))

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> showCode(reify(items.sorted).tree)
res0: String = $read.items.sorted(Ordering.Tuple2(Ordering.Char, Ordering.Int))
```

The `Ordering.Tuple2` here is a generic method that instantiates an `Ordering[(Char, Int)]`. This is exactly the same thing that happens when we define our `tupleOrdering`, but the difference is that in the `val` case it happens once, while in the case where it's resolved implicitly it happens every time `sorted` is called.

So the difference you're seeing is just the cost of instantiating the `Decoder` instance in every operation, as opposed to instantiating it a single time at the beginning outside of the benchmarked code. This cost is relatively tiny, and for larger benchmarks it's going to be more difficult to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot Travis!